# How to use screen in google cloud startup script?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terminal, debian, screen

So I decided to follow this  [minecraft server guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server#automate_start_up_and_shutdown_procedures), and I'm stuck on the part linked "Automate startup and shutdown procedures". It doesn't start the server. I have tried by replacing code with a simple `mkdir`, which works. So I know it is being executed.

Yet I can't connect to the screen `screen -list`, (both when going into sudo and my own user). I checked the `/run/screen/` folder and there's no other user.
It means it's safe to say that it fails, and not something I set up wrong.

The code I am using is the exact copy without the mounting nor the backup.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
cd /home/minecraft
screen -d -m -S mc java -Xms3G -Xmx7G -d64 -jar paper.jar nogui
```

Shouldn't this work?

EDIT: It works and I pasted the exact code I used. NOTE: I do use PaperMC, and a upgraded machine.

Comment: This will not work. Screen provides terminal sessions. The startup script process does not have a terminal session.

Comment: A startup script can be of any file type. If there is a startup script present, Compute Engine will do the following:   

1. Copy the startup script to a local file in the instance.   
2. Set permissions on the file to make it executable.   
3. Execute the file.   

In addition, the startup script require `compute.instances.setMetadata` as permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried [minecraft server guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server#automate_start_up_and_shutdown_procedures) myself and  its worked properly.
At the first time, I didnt find my mcs screen with `screen -list` but I remembered that GCE always executes startup scripts as root after the network is available.

So my next step was simply to change my user for root with the command `sudo su` and from this point, my mcs screen was available with `screen -list`.
*note that you can also use `sudo screen -list`*

I hope that will help, if not, what is your command output when its executed on your shell?:
`screen -d -m -S mc java -Xms1G -Xmx3G -d64 -jar server.jar nogui`

Comment: I am not sure what I was doing wrong, but it finally works. The code may have errored out somewhere along the way.